# Is it possible to pass a textbox value to a plugin

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I am using datatable plugin for sorting and pagination. I want to add a goto page button such that whenever someone gives a page-number it should goto a specific page and display the contents. Is it possible to pass a field value to plugin?
In my plugin I have this code...

```
e.childNodes[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
                        if (this.parentNode.classList.contains('active') ||
                            typeof this.dataset.page === 'undefined') {
                            return;
                        }
                        switch (this.dataset.page) {
                        case 'first':
                            dataTable.loadPage(1);
                            break;
                        case 'prev':
                            dataTable.loadPage(cp - 1);
                            break;
                        case 'next':
                            dataTable.loadPage(cp + 1);
                            break;
                        case 'last':
                            dataTable.loadPage(lp);
                            break;
                        default:
                            dataTable.loadPage(parseInt(parseInt(this.dataset.page), 10));
                        }
                    }, false);

loadPage: function (page) {
        var oldPage = this.currentStart / this.options.pageSize;
        if (page < 1) {
            page = 1;
        }
        else if (page > this.getLastPageNumber()) {
            page = this.getLastPageNumber();
        }
        this.currentStart = (page - 1) * this.options.pageSize;
        this.refresh();
        this.options.onChange.call(this.table, oldPage + 1, page);
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code where plugin having argument that we need to pass

Comment: please add this in question to avoid confusion

Comment: adding to this, what you want? Do you want how to get the value of textbox? Or do you want how to pass the variable that have this value from textbox to the datatable(Incase if its this can you share the datatable function too)?

Comment: I want to know how to pass the value to datatable